# Why setState in useEffect in not updating to the ref.current value supplied to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**What I want:** to get element(`<ul>`) scrollwidth inside of the style attribute inside DOM

**What I am trying:**

The `setSliderScrollWidth` in `useEffect` should update the state for `sliderScrollWidth` , the `sliderEl.current.scrollWidth` value is avaiable inside of the useEffect, but still inside of useEffect the `sliderScrollWidth` is 0.

Also I can not get `sliderEl.current.scrollWidth` inside of the DOM, so I am unable to get the inside of DOM with either useState or useRef.

```
const TextSlider = () => {
  const sliderEl = useRef(null);
  const [sliderScrollWidth, setSliderScrollWidth] = useState(0);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setSliderScrollWidth(sliderEl.current.scrollWidth);
    console.log(sliderScrollWidth, sliderEl.current.scrollWidth);
  },[])
 
  return(
     <ul
      ref={sliderEl}
      style={{
        width: `${sliderEl.current.scrollWidth}`,
      }}
    >
       <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

**What I don't understand**: *1)* Why if I can get `sliderEl.current.scrollWidth` inside of `useEffect` the `sliderScrollWidth` value is still 0? *2)* Why can't I get the ref.current value inside the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

> The `setSliderScrollWidth` in `useEffect` should update the state for `sliderScrollWidth` , `the sliderEl.current.scrollWidth` value is avaiable inside of the `useEffect`, but still inside of `useEffect` the `sliderScrollWidth` is 0.

Right, state updates [are not immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately). In a hooks-based component, calling the state setter will eventually make React call your component function again, and when it does your component function will get the updated value from `useState` into the *new* constant created for that call.

> Also I can not get `sliderEl.current.scrollWidth` inside of the DOM...

I assume you're referring to where you're trying to use it on the `style` prop. You can't do that, the element doesn't exist yet as of where you're trying to use `sliderEl.current.scrollWidth`, and `sliderEl` doesn't have a reference to it yet (because it doesn't exist).

You can set `sliderEl.current.style.width` in the effect callback, because at that point the DOM element will exist and `sliderEl` will have it:

```
const TextSlider = () => {
  const sliderEl = useRef(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    sliderEl.current.style.width = `${sliderEl.current.scrollWidth}px`;
  },[]);
 
  return(
     <ul
      ref={sliderEl}
    >
       <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

That's one of the purpose of `useEffect` (or `useLayoutEffect`, in some cases): To apply information to the DOM element you can't apply earlier.

Comment: *(Oops, typo. If you see "...the updated value from `useEffect`..." in the above, hit refresh, that should of course be `useState`.)*

Answer (score 0):

I think this little change can help you

In the end of `useEffect` put `,[sliderScrollWidth]`

```js
const TextSlider = () => {
  const sliderEl = useRef(null);
  const [sliderScrollWidth, setSliderScrollWidth] = useState(0);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setSliderScrollWidth(sliderEl.current.scrollWidth);
    console.log(sliderScrollWidth, sliderEl.current.scrollWidth);
  },[sliderScrollWidth])
 
  return(
     <ul
      ref={sliderEl}
      style={{
        width: `${sliderScrollWidth}`,
      }}
    >
       <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```